# Naming a JFrame after a String variable

Tags: java, swing, jframe

when you create a new JFrame you simply type:

```
    JFrame x = new JFrame();
```

And what I wonder is if there is a name to create a JFrame where "x = a String"
Here is a snippet of my code:

```
    public static void createWindow(String name, String title, int width, int height) {

        JFrame x /*I want it to be name*/ = new JFrame();
        name.setTitle(title);
        name.setSize(width, height);
        name.setVisible(true);

    }
```

This should then be called from another place with this command example:

```
createWindow(Name, Title, 200, 200);
```

and make a JFrame, but how do I input the 'Name' variable into x?

Comment: No that's not possible. Variable name should be defined upfront and not dynamic in nature.

Comment: i thinks not possible in java. but i am sure it is possible in scripting languages.. like javascript or actionscript.. then choose what you need

Comment: I have tried to replace
"public static void createWindow(String name, String title, int width, int height)"
with
"public static void createWindow(JFrame name, String title, int width, int height)"
witch fixed the errors, but I cannot still figure out how to CALL it now. Any clues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way you could work this out is using map. So if say i want multiple frame names then what i could do is:

```
Map<String, JFrame> map ..
map.put("myframe1", new JFrame..);
..
JFrame x = map.get(name);//this is what you could do in your method
```